# Copy text to clipboard on anchor tag click in VueJS issue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

In my laravel/Vue application,  I have an option to copy the link to the clipboard.

I have the following in my component.

```
<a @click="copyURL" ref="mylink">
        <img class="social_icon" 
          src="/images/game/copy.png"
        /></a>
        <input type="text" class="copyurl_txt" 
        value="https://mysite.site/" ref="text"></input>
```

in my scripts I have,

```
<script> 
export default {   
methods: {
            copyURL() {
              this.$refs.text.select();
              document.execCommand('copy');
            }
          },
};
</script>
```

This works well but Every time when I try to display none of the `copyurl_txt` it's not copying the value...

How can I copy the text(current value in the text field) to the clipboard on link click without displaying that text box...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to hide the input field, you can use the following CSS,

```
.copyurl_txt{
  max-width: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  border: transparent;
}
input[type=text]:focus{
  max-width: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  border: transparent;
  outline: none!important;
}
```

`'focus'` will hide the blue color out line of the textbox when it's selected.